# Snowflake: Issue with sub-query when tried mapping nearest dates

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to write a query in snowflake to map the nearest dates from 2 tables and below is the query for the same. The problem here is I am getting an issue with the below message.

> SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated

I tried this in R using sqldf package and it ran without any issue. I have 1.2 million records joining with 1.4 million records. I am unable to do this in R considering it's performance. Doing this in snowflake is resulting in this issue. Any alternative solution would be much helpful in resolving the issue.

```
WITH
without_verify AS (........), 
with_verify AS (.....)

SELECT distinct m.SUB, m.ID, m.NAME_FIELD, m.SUBCATEGORY_NAME, m.VALUE, m.SOURCE_TIMESTAMP, s.VERIFY_SOURCE_TIMESTAMP
FROM with_verify s
LEFT JOIN without_verify m
ON m.SUB = s.SUB
AND m.ID= s.ID
AND m.NAME_FIELD= s.NAME_FIELD
AND m.SOURCE_TIMESTAMP in (
    SELECT MAX(m2.SOURCE_TIMESTAMP)
    FROM without_verify m2
    WHERE m2.SUB= m.SUB
    AND m2.ID= m.ID
    AND m2.NAME_FIELD = m.NAME_FIELD
    AND m2.SOURCE_TIMESTAMP <= s.VERIFY_SOURCE_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but I suspect that because the right table is being used indirectly to filter the left table within a correlated subquery, Snowflake is freaking out. Generally when one filters the left table in a left outer join (where relationship to the right table isn't involved) the results are filtered before the join is attempted. Snowflake may be making the assumption that this is a pre-join filter but then when it goes to perform the logic it's finding the post-join right table present in the subquery.

Comment: At any rate, you may find luck in adding a third CTE that performs this filtering. `WITH without_verify2 as (SELECT * FROM without_verify WHERE m.SOURCE_TIMESTAMP in   SELECT MAX(m2.SOURCE_TIMESTAMP) ...`

Comment: Your sub-query is only going to return a single value so I'm not sure why you are using IN rather than =, but that may not be helping?

Comment: @NickW, I tried both but it did not help. I am getting the same error message.

Comment: @JNevill, I will try the approach you suggested and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

As documented [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-subqueries#types-supported-by-snowflake), a correlated subquery can only appear in a WHERE clause.

Move that last AND to a WHERE, and it should be OK assuming that there's nothing ugly hiding within those CTEs.